# Is this JavaScript-conversion of the POW-function correct?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a web app, in which we use formulas from a database for algebraic calculations.
So algebraic function like EXP must replaced by Math.exp etc.
The POW-function was little bit tricky.

I'm not sure if this formula is parsed correctly.

- **Formula**: `((KT * FK) * RT ^ 2) / QA`
- **Parsed formula**: `((KT * FK) * Math.pow(RT, 2)) / QA`

Is it correct or has the "*" priority?

Here the page from which i get the parsed formulas.
In the first Input i enter the formula and then i click the parse-button.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Parsing the Pow-function</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
    
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function ParseFormula(formula) {
                if (formula.indexOf("^") > -1) {
                    formula = formula.replace(/ /g, "");
                    var tab = [];
                    var powfunc = "Math.pow";
                    var joker = "___joker___";
                    while (formula.indexOf("(") > -1) {
                        formula = formula.replace(/(\([^\(\)]*\))/g, function (m, t) {
                            tab.push(t); //Adds the element t to the array
                            return (joker + (tab.length - 1));
                        });
                    }
    
                    tab.push(formula); //Adds the formula to the array
                    formula = joker + (tab.length - 1);
                    while (formula.indexOf(joker) > -1) {
                        formula = formula.replace(new RegExp(joker + "(\\d+)", "g"), function (m, d) {
                            return tab[d].replace(/(\w*)\^(\w*)/g, powfunc + "($1,$2)");
                        });
                    }
                }
                return formula;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>On this site the mathematical sign ^ is converted to Math.pow and the formula changed</h3>
        <input id="txtFormula" type="text" style="width:300px;" />
        <br /><br />
        <input id="txtParsedFormula" type="text" style="width:300px;" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="button" value="Parse" onclick="document.getElementById('txtParsedFormula').value = ParseFormula(document.getElementById('txtFormula').value);" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: No, we only accept code that works. This code does not work (or the author is not sure it does), and so it is off topic for CR.

Comment: The [precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) is grouping -> member access -> multiplication => correctly parsed.

Comment: Thank You Teemu. Meanwhile i have found an explanation on "Maths first" and it's really correct. As i wrote, the exponents are a little bit tricky.

Comment: @PatrickPirzer Notice, that algebraic operator precedence is not necessarily the same as JavaScript operator precedence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the page "Maths first" it seems to be correct.

For all numerical or algebraic expressions, the order of evaluation is ( BEDMAS ):

**B** rackets and Parentheses = First Priority

**E** xponents = Second Priority

**D** ivision = Third Priority

**M** ultiplication = Third Priority

**A** ddition = Fourth Priority

**S** ubtraction = Fourth Priority

[Order of algebraic operations](http://mathsfirst.massey.ac.nz/Algebra/OrderOfOp/orderAlg.htm)